# LINQ multiple where and if statements

Tags: c#, linq

How can I sort data with LINQ multiple times? I tried following, but it just returns all Customers.

```
var query = this.dbContext.Customers;
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sortFilterName))
{
    query.Where(q => q.Name.Equals(sortFilterName));
}
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sortFilterAddress))
{
    query.Where(q => q.Adress.Equals(sortFilterAddress));
}
return query.ToList();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your need to assing your `query` variable to the result of filtering:

```
var query = this.dbContext.Customers;
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sortFilterName))
{
    query = query.Where(q => q.Name.Equals(sortFilterName));
}
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sortFilterAddress))
{
    query = query.Where(q => q.Adress.Equals(sortFilterAddress));
}
return query.ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks, that was simple. Also found out that after posting this (spent 1 hour thinking about this before).